Buscador con Api de Google
Actualmente estoy armando un sitio en WordPress: preciosbarriales.com.ar y necesito crear un buscador que esté basado en la API de Google Maps para mostrar resultados determinados previamente en función de la localidad/ código postal que ingrese el usuario en el buscador.
Por el momento armé esto, pero no le estoy encontrando la vuelta, logré que se muestre el mapa, que tenga la entrada para buscar, el mapa responde a esa acción y muestra locales varios pero que no son los que yo quiero presentar.
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

<form id="search-form">
    <input type="text" id="postal-code" placeholder="Ingrese código postal">
    <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>

<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: { lat: -34.603722, lng: -58.381592 }
        });

        var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        document.getElementById('search-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var postalCode = document.getElementById('postal-code').value;

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ address: postalCode }, function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    var location = results[0].geometry.location;

                    var request = {
                        location: location,
                        radius: 3000,
                        type: 'store'
                    };

                    placesService.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
                        if (status === 'OK') {
                            markers.forEach(function(marker) {
                                marker.setMap(null);
                            });
                            markers = [];

                            results.forEach(function(place) {
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: place.geometry.location,
                                    map: map,
                                    title: place.name
                                });

                                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                                    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                                        'Dirección: ' + place.vicinity + '<br>' +
                                        'Tipo: ' + place.types.join(', ') + '</div>');
                                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                });

                                markers.push(marker);
                            });

                            map.setCenter(location);
                        } else {
                            alert('No se encontraron lugares cercanos. Intente con otro código postal.');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    if (status === 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
                        alert('No se encontraron resultados para el código postal proporcionado. Intente con otro código postal.');
                    } else {
                        alert('No se pudo completar la búsqueda. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde.');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }

    var markers = [];
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=TU_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>

Lo inserté desde un bloque de Html pero no se como decirle los resultados que quiero que muestre. Los resultados los tengo en un archivo de Mi Maps de Google.
Se que es muy abierta la pregunta pero ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?
